# Determine user if the user has a pending request

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, user-controls

I have Leave Form that is created in InfoPath and Published it to sharepoint 2013.

My task is to determine if the user/employee has a Pending Leave request and not allowing the user/employee to create new one if the request is not completed.

Could this be possible? Hope someone could help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: @kurt allen please mark the suggested response as answer if found useful.

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, but after the edit this doesn't seem a dupe of the specified question anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Can you **on form load check if there is an open request for the current user**, using a secondary connection.

If so switch to a view or something to prompt the user regarding existing leave request and you migth as well provide a link to the pending request.

Comment: Thank you bkk for you reply, i just wondering how to do that on the Form Load that checks the open request of the current user. can you please guide me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There is a different way to solve this, if possible.

Before even showing the click button of the "Create new request", may be you can check if the user has submitted the form. The idea here is to pre-check the condition before even opening the InfoPath form. This way it will simplify the form too.

I'm not sure how the create new request appears in your site now. But I hope this gives you an alternate way of doing the same thing. All the best :)